# Phaser.Scene: how to make the `game` property available?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In a webpack/babel environment, I run an example similar to this one (available in the [Phaser 3 Sandbox](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/scenes/scene%20from%20es6%20class.js)); I just added a `console.log(this)` and removed the image `load()` and `add()`:

```
class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor (config)
    {
        super(config);
    }

    preload ()
    {
        console.log(this);
    }

    create ()
    {
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.WEBGL,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    scene: MyScene
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

It's working, but there is one difference between my own local example and the online Phaser 3 Sandbox:

- In my local example, the `game` property is not available into the `MyScene` instance;
- In the online sandbox, I can see this property is existent (by adding the same `console.log(this)`).

I noticed that I can get the `Game` instance with `Phaser.Scene.sys.game`, but I wonder why I don't have the same resulting object between the online sandbox and my own example.

You can read this in the [Phaser 3 API Documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scene.html) about `Phaser.Scene.game`:

> game :Phaser.Game
>
> A reference to the Phaser.Game instance.
>   This property will only be available if defined in the Scene Injection Map.

So I tried to modify the Scene Injection Map inside the `MyScene` constructor, but I don't really understand it for now, and all my tries about it sadly failed.

What should I change in order to make the `game` property available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found [this post](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/38636-thisgame-or-thissysgame/) which seems to answer the question:

> Hi, Scenes have property game (Phaser.Game), but it seems to be
>   undefined all the time (in preload, create or update methods of
>   scene). Doc says: "This property will only be available if defined in
>   the Scene Injection Map." and I can see it in default injection map
>   ... but still undefined.
>
> On the other side, there is sys property (object) with game property
>   in it. I can get game reference like this.sys.game instead of
>   this.game.
>
> Is it correct to use this.sys.game? Why is not this.game working? Is
>   it some leftover from older version?

Answer from an admin:

> Yeah it shouldn’t be exposed at all. I’ll remove it from the map. It
>   should almost never be used.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which was "what should I modify to make `game` available to my scene." The linked post from html5gamedevs also does not answer it. This answer is no help to anyone with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, but I got the properties I sent as follows.

when calling the scene i sent properties like this

```
this.scene.start("game", { mode: "watch" })
```

I used this method to access the properties I posted

```
  this.scene.settings.data.mode;
```

hope it helped